# Почему — сопка?

Tags: этимология, диалекты

Почему горы на Дальнем Востоке называют сопками? И все ли горы так называют? Это какой-то местный диалект? Откуда вообще это слово?

Answer (score 8):

Всю жизнь живу на Дальнем Востоке. На сопках и в окружении сопок.  Не могу сказать, что живу на горе ))), или загорать на гору ходила. Только на сопку. Для меня гора - это ГОРА, она высокая.  А сопки не очень. Это исконно русское слово от глагола сыпать. Как диалектное - нет, не думаю. Кстати, горы у нас тоже есть. И если совершают восхождение, то на гору, а не на сопку.

Comment: Никогда вживую не видела сопку, знаю лишь то, что так говорят на Дальнем Востоке и в Сибири о небольшой горе с округлой вершиной. Признаться, ни разу не слышала, чтобы говорили на небольшую гору с округлой вершиной "сопка". Думаю, это все-таки диалектное слово.

Comment: Ещё в Мурманске так говорят.

Comment: Серьезно? А я думала, это чисто дальневосточное слово. Но по поводу невысоких год. А как быть с вулканом Ключевская Сопка? Он ведь немаленький.

Answer (score 2):

В Большом энциклопедическом словаре СОПКА -1) общее название холмов и гор с округлой вершиной в Забайкалье и на Дальнем Востоке России, а также вулканов на Камчатке и Курильских о-вах, грязевых вулканов в Крыму и на Кавказе.2) В археологии название высоких (св. 4 м) курганов, преимущественно 8-10 вв., приписываемых славянам новгородским.

Б. Энциклопед. словарь Ф.А. Брокгауза и И.А. Ефрона говорит, что это русское народное название для уединенных более или менее крутых гор с каменистой вершиной, распространяемое и на отдельные возвышенности, выдающиеся в горном хребте или массиве. Особенно употребительно на Урале и в Сибири, где горой по большей части называется только более или менее крутой подъем местности. На Камчатке название сопка применяется, по-видимому, преимущественно к вулканам. В побережьях Черного и Каспийского морей С. или блеваками называются грязевые вулканы.

Как видим,сопками в разных местностях называют и вершины гор, и уединённые горы (их как бы отдельно насыпали), и насыпанные курганы (высокие сакрально-погребальные насыпи эпохи массовой славянской колонизации Новгородской земли в X веке), и вулканы (но тогда возводят это слово к глаголу "сопеть"), и грязевые вулканы(но тогда их чаще называют блеваками, понятно почему).Так что похоже действительно на "областное" слово, близкое к диалектам, хотя таких пометок и нет, а вот Фасмер указал -"архангельское", признал диалектом.

Comment: Действительно, в словарях пометы диалектное нет. Согласна со словарями. Мне почему-то казалось, что у диалектного слова территория распространения поменьше. Не случайно диалектное  - то же, что и областное. А здесь Сибирь и Дальний Восток (Сибирь, Хабаровский край,Приморье,Амурская область, Сахалин,Курилы, Камчатка). Не многовато для областного?

Comment: Но у нас в Поволжье тоже есть горы конусообразные, есть и одиночные, однако сопок нет, только горы. Или холмы, если поменьше.А вот в Казахстане, в Забайкалье и на Дальнем Востоке это же называют сопкой. А на Камчатке и на Курилах сопками называют только вулканы. Спящий вулкан - сопка (от сопеть, спать)вполне мотивировано , их так везде называют, а вот как бы насыпанные холмы почему-то по-разному называют на Западе и на Востоке. Вот это, по-моему, близко к восточным (зауральским)диалектам.

Comment: @Людмила сопки ещё и на Кольском полуострове есть. Карельские сопки, по идее, и должны были получить своё название первыми. В отличии от холма, сопка - это, в кольском понимании, скала, но недостаточно большая, чтобы её называть горой.

Comment: Ээээ, что-то они в энциклопедии не доработали)))) Я всю жизнь живу в Крыму, но ни разу не слышала, что наши грязевые вулканы называли сопками)))) Вулканы — и вулканы)))